# Gradle build for Java project is failing

Tags: gradle

Below build.gradle file for java project is failing

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.+'
    testCompile "log4j:log4j:1.2.9"
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8'
        }


test {
  // enable TestNG support 

 task testNGTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()    {
    suites 'src/test/resources/testng.xml'
    useDefaultListeners = true
    }
}
}
```

Error:

Couldnot find property  'projectDir' on org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGOptions_Decorated@1595f1bb.

Then I tried in using setting.gradle file with below code:

rootProject.name = 'AutoTest_Gradle'
project(':AutoTest_Gradle').projectDir = 'C:/workspace/AutoTest_Gradle'

Here AutoTest_Gradle is the project name.Then it is failed with below error:

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\workspace\AutoTest_Gradle\settings.gradle
- What went wrong:`enter code here
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'AutoTest_Gradle'.

  > Project with path ':AutoTest_Gradle' could not be found.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Don't you need to include project first, with: `include ':AutoTest_Gradle'`?

Comment: It is failed with error  * What went wrong:
Could not select the default project for this build. Multiple projects in this b
uild have project directory 'C:\workspace\AutoTest_Gradle': [project ':AutoTest_
Gradle', root project 'AutoTest_Gradle']
> Multiple projects in this build have project directory 'C:\workspace\AutoTest_
Gradle': [project ':AutoTest_Gradle', root project 'AutoTest_Gradle']